# No Id found viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app with 3 tabs. A tab has a fragment with a button to go another view within the same tab. My implementation is simple. I have main_activity with view pager. Here is snippet of main_activity.xml.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Below the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public SectionsPageAdapter mSectionPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSectionPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
    //Assigns the ViePager to TabLayout
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

//Defines the number of tabs by setting appropriate fragment and tab name.
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FirsTab(),"TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecondTab(),"TAB2");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThirdTab(),"TAB3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

When I replace the FirstTab with FirsTabSubFragment with getChildFragmentManager() I get a "no view found" error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0073 (com.none.app:id/pager) for fragment FirsTabSubFragment{607b4a6 #0 id=0x7f0d0073}
```

Below the code for FirtTab.java

```
public class FirstTab extends Fragment{

private Button btnScan;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_layout, container, false);
    btnScan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

    btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.pager, new FirsTabSubFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

A replacement with a getFragmentmanager() results in a empty view. Can anyone advice me on this topic?

Comment: Have you got error when click on btnScan button ?

Comment: yes when I click on the button I get "No view found" error.

Comment: your pager id is not in fragments scan_layout due to that your getting this error

Comment: what should be the solution? the view pager should act as container to swap the fragments.

Comment: If you want to add another fragment in First Tab then you need to add fragment/FrameLayout in FirstTab's layout file

Comment: You mean static? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/homeFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent>// your scan screen layout
</FrameLayout>

Comment: getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.homeFrameLayout, new FirsTabSubFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

Comment: Great! it works...but it won't replace old fragment. Both fragments are visible  at the same time.

Comment: instead if add use replace  getChildFragmentManager() .beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.homeFrameLayout, new FirsTabSubFragment()) .addToBackStack(null) .commit();

Comment: Or set background to replacing Fragment

Comment: I did use use replace instead of add and background for the fragments are all the same.

Comment: For example I use a button in the FirsTab. This button is still visible if the next fragment is replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your effort btw..

Comment: @J Ramesh I have looked at multiple answers and tried to use but none of them worked. Do you have solution for this problem?

Comment: I am already given solution on above comments

Comment: Can you please share scan_layout.xml

Comment: ok No problem. Found the solution.